# Apply dynamic filters using Tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, tags, angularjs-filter

I have a list of elements which is displayed in a table using ng-repeat. I want to apply dynamic filters which are added using Tags([ng-tags-input](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput)). This tag input generates dynamic tags which I want to use as filters.

Here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MiMT4T1Fdkcx9xRhi1ub?p=preview) I have created. How can I use entries from these tags to create filters.

For a single element i tried

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
    <table border=1 cellpadding=10px>
        <tr ng-repeat = "t in tableData | filter:tags[0].text">
            <td>{{t.data1}}</td>
            <td>{{t.data2}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

but this will take only a single element. I want to apply entire entries of `tags` to be a filter.

I have seen other questions on SO, but they have filters applied as

`<tr ng-repeat = "t in tableData | filter:{data1:someFilteData}">`

Here is one of the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ed9A2/1/). I am not able to apply filter from JSON Array.
How can I do this?

Comment: Give an example of a possible input and desired output.

Comment: See this http://plnkr.co/edit/MiMT4T1Fdkcx9xRhi1ub?p=preview .
Here I want to use tags to get filter data as I want to apply multiple filters. Then I want to pass the tags as filters.
Possible Input : data1, data3 (as tags)
Possible Output: Table data filtered through data1 and data3

Comment: Yes but what does _"filtered through data1 and data3"_ mean ? What should be returned ? Items that have a key that matches either dat1 or data3 ? Items that have keys to match both data1 and data3 ? Compare with values instead of keys ? What should be returned in your fiddle example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include items that have a property-value that matches at least one of the tags, you can define your custom filter like this:

```
app.filter('filterByTags', function () {
    return function (items, tags) {
        var filtered = []; // Put here only items that match
        (items || []).forEach(function (item) { // Check each item
            var matches = tags.some(function (tag) {          // If there is some tag
                return (item.data1.indexOf(tag.text) > -1) || // that is a substring
                       (item.data2.indexOf(tag.text) > -1);   // of any property's value
            });                                               // we have a match
            if (matches) {           // If it matches
                filtered.push(item); // put it into the `filtered` array
            }
        });
        return filtered; // Return the array with items that match any tag
    };
});
```

And the use it like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in tableData | filterByTags:tags">
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xVzwlOlwaYuo7K37QURD?p=preview)**.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I thought that this can be done with built in filters without creating a custom filter on my own. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If I delete all the tags, the table shows no element at all. What modifications should be made so that, if there is no tag, the table will show all entries?

I have this Plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/3MLi92cuRkw96xz644Zg?p=preview. Can you verify if this is the correct way to do this?

Also , in your code `(items || []).forEach(function (item) { // Check each item` , I don't understand the reason you have used `items || []`, the items is anyway never an empty array. Can you explain this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your implementation is correct - one remark: It is better to place the check on the top of the function (`if (tags.length === 0) { return items; }`), so you avoid the unnecessary calculations.

Comment: Regarding your other question, `(items || [])` is a "safeguard" for the case that our filter is passed an `undefined` argument (e.g. if data was fetched from the backend and you forgot to initialize `tableData` to an empty array (until the actual data arrives), our filtered would try to call `forEach` on `undefined` and you would get an error in the console. `(items || [])` means: "use `items` unless it is falsy (e.g. `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `''`, `0`); then use `[]`). I hope it does make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. And yes, it makes more sense now.

Comment: One more thing, how to make it as case insensitive? Convert both parameters to lowercase and then match? Can you modify the existing Plunk to do just this as I don't know where to use `angular.lowercase`

Comment: Check out this Plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/U5K4tgla0JCRlwbUY3vB?p=preview

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Here is an alternative implementation that might be more efficient: http://plnkr.co/edit/63kKR9cyvyxWogyP4GB5?p=preview (but unless your table is huge, you won't see any noticable difference in performance)