# Filter ngtagsinput in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, ng-tags-input

I have some trouble with filtering JSON data by tags with AngularJS.
I tried this slightly modified filter by ExpertSystem ([Apply dynamic filters using Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785592/angularjs-apply-dynamic-filters-using-tags)) here:

```
groupifyApp.filter('filterByTags', function () {
    return function (items, tags) {
        var filtered = [];
        if (tags.length == 0) {
            filtered = items;
        }
        (items || []).forEach(function (item) {
            var matches = tags.some(function (tag) {
                return (item.data1.indexOf(tag.text) > -1) || (item.data2.indexOf(tag.text) > -1);
            });
            if (matches) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

And in my HTML:

```
<tags-input ng-model="searchTags" type="text" placeholder="Search tags">
        <auto-complete source="allTags()"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
    Model: {{searchTags}}
    <br />
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <th>Group name</th>
            <th>Tags</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Looking for</th>
            <th class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</th>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="match in allGroups | filterByTags:searchTags">
            <td>{{match.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="tag in match.tags">{{tag}}</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>{{match.type}}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="deficit in match.deficits">{{deficit}}</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left"></span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The JSON look like that:

```
[
        {name: "Elite", type: "Learning", tags: ["RWTH", "Aachen"], competences: ["Complexity"], deficits: ["Java"], members: ["Niklas", "Marv"]},
        {name: "Old Boys", type: "Assignments", tags: ["FH", "Aachen"], competences: ["Java"], deficits: ["AAT"], members: ["Joel", "Joel's Sister"]}
    ];
```

Unfortunately the table isn't filtered. It always prints out the whole table (even w/o my modification).
I guess I have todefine which column shall be filtered, but I'm not really familiar with AngularJS or JavaScript at all. So any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your item types in filter function.

```
groupifyApp.filter('filterByTags', function () {
     return function (items, tags) {
            var filtered = [];
            (items || []).forEach(function (item) {
                var matches = tags.some(function (tag) {
                    return (item.name.indexOf(tag.text) > -1) ||
                           (item.type.indexOf(tag.text) > -1) ||
                           (item.tags.indexOf(tag.text) > -1) ||
                           ((item.competences).indexOf(tag.text) > -1) ||
                           ((item.members).indexOf(tag.text) > -1) ||
                           (item.deficits.indexOf(tag.text) > -1);
                });
                if (matches) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            });
            if (tags.length == 0) {
                filtered = items;
            }
            return filtered;
        };
    });
```

Hope this helps. Btw If your object is integer, you have to change object type to string. To be specific:

{name: "Elite", age: 18, type: "Learning", tags: ["RWTH", "Aachen"], competences: ["Complexity"], deficits: ["Java"], members: ["Niklas", "Marv"]},

```
 ((item.age+"").indexOf(tag.text) > -1) ||
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just chain the promise you get back from wherever. I HTML you'll have the auto-complete directive within the tags input. 'filter.values' is the list of tags that have been filled in.

```
<tags-input ng-model="filter.values">
    <auto-complete load-on-down-arrow="true"
                   debounce-delay="0"
                   min-length="1"
                   source="getTagsFromAPI ($query, filter.id)">
    </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

I have a service which I called 'filterService'  which has a function 'getAutoCompleteList', which returns all possible values from the API:

```
$scope.getTagsFromAPI = function($query, filterId) {
    return filterService.getAutoCompleteList(filterId).then(function(result) {
         return _.filter(result, function(q){
            return _.contains(q.text, $query);
        });
    });
};
```

This function returns a promise, and I resolve the promise by adding '.then()' after is. I then use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to filter the result according to the '$query' passed in. You could also loop through the list yourself and compare, but I like to use underscore for this. Since the [promises have been chained](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-promises), I can then simply return the result.