# ng-table, ng-repeat, filter works only for the current page, in a paginated table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I implemented a custom filter for my ng-table, where it uses ngTagInput. Link[1] is similar to my code, this filter does works only with the current page. 
What is the correct way of getting all the results to get filtered in ng-repeat.

---

code snippet for filter:

```
.filter('filterByTags', function () {
    return function (items, tags) {
        var i = 0;
        var filtered = []; // Put here only items that match
        (items || []).forEach(function (item) { // Check each item
            var matches = tags.some(function (tag) {          // If there is some tag
                i++;
                return (item.name.indexOf(tag.name) > -1)    // that is a substring
            });                                               // we have a match
            if (matches) {           // If it matches
                filtered.push(item); // put it into the `filtered` array
            }
        });
        if(i == 0){
            return items;
        }
        else{
            return filtered;
        }
    };
})
```

---

[1] [Filter ngtagsinput in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220994/filter-ngtagsinput-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem that the filter was working only on the current page. The original question did not include the HTML, just a link to similar code, so I'm not sure if my solution would be applicable to the original question, but it might help others struggling with paging and filtering. My HTML looked like this, with the paging before the filtering:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | pages: myCtrl.currentPage : myCtrl.itemsPerPage | filter: searchCriteria">
```

I changed the HTML to put the filtering before the paging, and then the filter worked on all the pages:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchCriteria | pages: myCtrl.currentPage : myCtrl.itemsPerPage">
```