# angularjs filter ng-repeat links outside of list

Tags: angularjs

Building a simple app that filters results based on an input field. I'm adding a bunch of links that are outside of the repeated list and when clicked I want to be able to filter the list below.

I've searched online for various ways of tackling this problem but have yet to find a solution.

I'm already filtering by search, however I'd like to be able to click a link that is a popular search entry.

My code is:

```
<a href="">tag one</a>
<a href="">tag two</a>
<a href="">tag three</a>

<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'date' | filter:itemsFilter" ng-click="clickedItem(item.id)">
      <td><a href="{{item.url}}"><img ng-src="{{item.imageUrl}}" alt="{{item.title}}"></a></td>
      <td>
        <a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.title}}</a><br>
      </td>
      <td><i class="el el-time"></i> {d{item.date}}</td>
      <td class="drop-me">{{item.description}}</td>
      <td class="tag-me">{{item.tag}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-hide="item.length == 0"><td><p>There are no items!</p></td></tr>
```

I've tried custom filters, just can't figure a way to inject the items via an ng-click and update the list below.

I'd like to click one of the tag links and it filter the list below

Thanks

Comment: can you provide the relevant controller code

Comment: Please offer a better explanation of what you need help with.  I think you're asking about a custom filter but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is itemsFilter?

Comment: itemsFilter is a search box further up the code that filters the list

Comment: Controller code calls a factory and then populates the $scope.items with the result.

Comment: By what property do you want to filter with links?

Comment: Inside the items there's an item.tag that has a list of tags associated with the list item. I'd like to use that as the filter mechanism

Comment: Create filters array, on link click push item to it. Then create custom filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in the comments you can create an array to which you're adding your tags for filtering and in a custom filter you can filter your items array.

Also [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) is a nice directive that's helping to create a input field with tags.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/2sddt77j/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngTagsInput'])
  // filter from here (with some modifications) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785592/apply-dynamic-filters-using-tags
  .filter('filterByTags', function() {
    return function(items, tags) {
      var filtered = []; // Put here only items that match
      (items || []).forEach(function(item) { // Check each item
        var matches = tags.some(function(tag) { // If there is some tag
          return item.tag == tag.text;
        }); // we have a match
        if (matches) { // If it matches
          filtered.push(item); // put it into the `filtered` array
        }
      });
      return filtered.length == 0 ? items : filtered; // Return the array with items that match any tag // return all if no tags
    };
  })
  .controller('mainController', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl() {
  var vm = this;

  function isTagInTags(tag) {
    var seen = false;
    //console.log('test', tag);
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.tags.length; i++) {
      //console.log(vm.tags[i].text, tag);
      if (vm.tags[i].text == tag) {
        seen = true;
        return seen;
      }
    }
    return seen;
  }

  vm.addTag = function(tag) {
    //console.log(tag);
    if (!isTagInTags(tag)) {
      vm.tags.push({
        text: tag
      });
    }
  };

  vm.data = [{
    id: 0,
    tag: 'JavaScript',
    title: 'this is JS related'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    tag: 'Java',
    title: 'this is Java related'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    tag: 'Python',
    title: 'this is Python related'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    tag: 'Python',
    title: 'also Python stuff...'
  }];

  var unique = [];
  vm.availTags = [];
  for (i in vm.data) {
    var item = vm.data[i];
    //console.log(item);
    if (unique.indexOf(item.tag) === -1) {
      unique.push(item.tag);
      vm.availTags.push(item.tag);
    }
  }

  vm.loadItems = function(query) {
      //console.log(query);
      return vm.availTags.filter(function(tag) {
        var testTag = tag.toLowerCase();
        return testTag.indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      });
      //return $http.get('/tags?query=' + query); // use this with a backend
    }
    //console.log(vm.availTags);

  vm.tags = []; //vm.availTags[0];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/3.1.1/ng-tags-input.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
  <button ng-click="ctrl.addTag('JavaScript')">
    JavaScript
  </button>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.addTag('Java')">
    Java
  </button>
  <!--{{ctrl.tags}}-->
  <tags-input ng-model="ctrl.tags">
    <auto-complete source="ctrl.loadItems($query)"></auto-complete>
  </tags-input>

  <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.data | filterByTags: ctrl.tags">
    {{item.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try addition **ng-href**

```
<a ng-href="">tag one</a>
<a ng-href="">tag two</a>
<a ng-href="">tag three</a>

<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'date' | filter:itemsFilter" ng-click="clickedItem(item.id)">
      <td><a ng-href="{{item.url}}"><img ng-src="{{item.imageUrl}}" alt="{{item.title}}"></a></td>
      <td>
        <a ng-href="{{item.url}}">{{item.title}}</a><br>
      </td>
      <td><i class="el el-time"></i> {d{item.date}}</td>
      <td class="drop-me">{{item.description}}</td>
      <td class="tag-me">{{item.tag}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-hide="item.length == 0"><td><p>There are no items!</p></td></tr>
```